# Remove characters after specific character for dynamic titles

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey I would like to cut off a title from an RSS feed after a specific character, in this case, the character ";". I looked up plenty of questions and they all seem to do this with a predefined string. I need my code to pull the title of an RSS feed (which is dynamic, but always in a similar format with the ";" I want to delete the contents before). Here's my Code

ASP.NET - P.S I'm using a fancybox iframe to pull the link up. Its irrelevant to my issue.

```
<a href="<%# XPath("link") %>" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" scrolling="no"><%# FormatTitle( XPath("title") ) %></a>
```

C# - I made this code after searching similar questions on StackOverflow

```
public static string FormatTitle(object TitleIn)
    {
        string input = "Bid - Contract.: 13-C-00038; Howard F. Curren AWTP New Primary Sludge Pump Station Rehabilitation &amp;#8211; Sheltered Market";
            int index = input.IndexOf(";") + 1;
            if (index > 0)
                input= input.Substring(index);
            return input;
    }
```

Now, the problem is now that all of my feeds have the same title, "Howard F. Curren AWTP New Primary Sludge Pump Station Rehabilitation &#8211; Sheltered Market". I need the "input" string to accept the "title" field on the xml that's being pulled. Sorry if this has already been answered. I looked up a bunch on StackOverflow and I can't find any that deal with dynamic titles.

Comment: Why don't you replace the `string input = ...` line with `string input = TitleIn`?

Comment: I agree with the above comment. Not knowing anything about your TitleIn object and assuming it has a string property called Title: it would probably look something like string input = TitleIn ? TitleIn.Title : "Default Title";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code ignores the input param TitleIn and uses the local variable input that is set to the string literal. Hence, your method will always return the same value.

Comment: Woops, yea. Its one of those days. I had to make the object into a string and run it through. Yep, thanks. :-)